# Touch screen not working after some reboots (another reboot resolves it)

Tags: hardware, cpu, reboot, touchscreen

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue on a Lenovo Flex 14 with Ubuntu 14.04.1 (standard Unity flavour) with touchscreen.

Mostly it works perfectly well; but from time to time I reboot (mostly unintentionally due to the placement of the power button, but sometimes because of auto update [updating the kernel??]), and when it does, *on some reboots* the touchscreen does not work (does not respond to touch).

I have tried during these occurrences, doing as full a dump as I could of

- `cpuinfo`
- `lsmod`
- `lspci`
- `lsusb`

to text files.

When I reboot, the touchscreen is fine again. Both times when I let the laptop boot, I do not change any settings or add any options. I just let it boot on its own.

So I dump the same information again.

As far as I can see, nothing is different except for the processor speed - which during non-functioning touch-screen consistently displays a slower CPU speed in cpuinfo (c. 750 MHz instead of c. 1000 MHz - not in front of me right now, but thereabouts).

Other than that, I see no discrepancies between the two dumps (used `sort` and `diff` to confirm this)

Does anyone have any tips I can try to see where I could glean any info (other /proc/* dumps or commands to troubleshoot)? Does the change in clock speed mean anything to anyone? (and where should I dump logs to if required?)

Thanks

~taikedz

EDIT: Yes, I know rebooting "solves" the issue in the immediate - but I'm more interested in troubleshooting tips than anyone actually having an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't reboot directly but first shutdown then start it. This is probably some driver problem. Hope it helps!